# Android Location Wifi doesnt work after rebooting

Tags: android, location

I am using this code to get the location provider and location.

```
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        mBestProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mBestProvider);
```

If I turn off the GPS, the location is by network, but if I reboot the phone(so I loss the last position known) and with the 3G data connections off. So I am only using WIFI, I cant get any provider thus therefore any location. However google places app can locate me. I think it might be getting the lastknownlocation.But in that case my others applications should be able to get that location. Any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 3):

The way you are calling this it will return all providers enabled or not because you are passing it false which is probably your intention but have you checked the return string?

```
mBestProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
```

You might be getting the gps provider, or you might be getting the network provider, I have learned not to trust the criteria mechanism because it seems to work differently per carrier and device (I have had some weird bugs reported because of this)

So I always ask specifically for *gps and network* providers and check last known for both, then use an algo to determine the best one to use.

The network provider can use cell *or* wifi hotspot/routers to determine location (google keeps a database of wifi information) so it's possible to get a fix with just wifi, not saying that is whats happening but it could be.

If that bears no fruit then it's possible that they are simply caching the last location update in preferences, some applications do that.  To test the thesis, failing all of the above just leave the phone in that state and move to a very different location with the same properties if possible, should only take 2000 meters or so. If your app still reports null and places reports the old location you have your answer.

If places did report the newer location with wifi, and your app cannot (assuming you actually verify you are getting the network provider) then there is a chance they are using a private API via the Google Location Server (GLS) / MASF server via partial cell / wifi info but that's at the extreme end of the tin foil curve.

Comment: I have add a condition to set NETWORK_PROVIDER in case the criteria mechanism returns nothing, and when I use mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mBestProvider) I get no result. So I cant get any position. I will do the test you said, as I think probably they store in preferences the position.

Comment: neither GPS/NETWORK/PASSIVE providers returns anything. I have done a test: Disable the WIFI and remove cache/application data from places app.When I open places again it says "Requiere a Data Connection" I turn on WIFI again, and then appear position with 50meters precission. Does it means they are using a second "secret" API? Cause with the WIFI on and manually set NEWTWORK_PROVIDER I get nothing.

Comment: @dayerman Have you actually tried setting up a location listener etc. with the network provider? The getLastLocation can return null but still report location updates to a registered listener, it could be they are just getting actual updates. If you don't then I think that's an indication something else is going on, but I would check it first.

Comment: Good!It's sort of OK, but when the app starts the listener doesnt execute, but if I switch OFF and ON the Wifi, then I got a location.Any help to get the solution?So, if the application starts with only wifi but this is enabled, then the listener doesnt fire, so i dont get a position until the wifi swith OFF and ON

Comment: long MINTIME = 10000;float MINDISTANCE = 10; I have wait 60sec and nothing happends

Comment: Sorry but setting MINTIME to 0 doesnt change anything.

Comment: Ok well you can register for a passive provider with 0/0 that should relay places (or any location listener in the system) updates directly to you when they happen, you can't use it as the only provider because it's not a reliable mechanism, but it should allow you get updates at the same frequency as places does.  Failing that you could muck with the network provider settings to try and induce a refresh but thats a hack.

Comment: First option means that I have to open first places for my app to work. I will try 2nd option, but I think should be another way to do it.